# Android: TabHost only create a single LinearLayout which can be referenced

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, android-tabhost

```
    ArrayList<LinearLayout> llal = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();        
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        final int temp = i;
        String tabName = "tab " + i;
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(tabName);

        TabHost.TabContentFactory tcf = new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
            @Override
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //return llarray[temp];
                LinearLayout myll = new LinearLayout(TabActivity.this);
                llal.add(myll);
                myll.setId(View.generateViewId());
                myll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                MyFragment mf = MyFragment.newInstance("hi");
                ft.add(myll.getId(), mf).commit();
                return myll;
            }
        };
        tabSpec.setContent(tcf);
        tabSpec.setIndicator(tabName);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }
```

What I am trying to do here is I am trying to create tab dynamically, and each tab will contain a LinearLayout to add their respective Fragment. What I am trying to do is that I would like to access LinearLayout for each created tab, therefore I plan to save them into an array for reference. In this example, I used an ArrayList to test the amount of LinearLayout that will be added to the ArrayList. When I call the `myll.size()` it gave me the value 1 which indicate that only the 1st created LinearLayout could be referenced. 
Could anyone explain to me why do this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I know where is the problem. Although it is a little bit late, but I would like to inform others about the problem. The reason why it give value 1 is because that in Android, the tabs are not created unless you viewed them. Therefore that approach doesn't work. Hope this will help someone who get null pointer exception.